# to make a bootable USB for windows 10

Tags: usb

Ware can I get clean ISO of Windows 10 creators update (Build 15063), FCU (Build 16299.15), April 2018 Update (Build 17134.1)? I find this link on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0YmSdr6K2s the person never left the link on his page and I can't see the name of the website he gets the file, I left a message on his youtube account but he has not respond.

Answer (score 0):

You would be lucky to just get the current Windows 10 right now. Goto Microsoft and **get the latest Windows 10 build**.

> March 10, 2020—KB4540705 (OS Build 15063.2313)
>
> Current status of Windows 10, version 1703
>
> Windows 10, version 1703 has reached end of service for all editions. To continue receiving security and quality updates, Microsoft recommends updating to the latest version of Windows 10.
>
> Surface Hub devices remain in support. Starting on November 12, 2019, updates for Windows 10, version 1703 will be available only for Surface Hub devices. Update information and Surface Hub known issues will be listed on this page.
>
> For information about servicing timelines, 
>   [see the Windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet).
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4540705/windows-10-update-kb4540705

Why would would want only that particular Windows 10?

I don't think Microsoft allows you to download that, I have tried an old link, I get "Forbidden". Good Luck.